# UDK license (DLLBind)

Tags: udk, licensing

I dont understand part of UDK's license about [DLLBind](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DLLBind.html):

does it allow to use DLLBind in UDK projects? Could I use DLLBind for commercial games without buying c++/native license?

Comment: It says clearly you can bind 1 DLL per class (script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This functionality is intended for use by UDK developers

What don't you understand?

Comment: this is not really an answer to the questions. "Does the license agreement allow DLLBind to be used in UDK projections? Could I use DLLBind for commercial games without buying a c++/native license?"

Comment: "This functionality is intended for use by UDK developers".